# Difficulty of parsing (and translating) a certain clause with the word "way"

Tags: word-usage

In a birthday wish for "someone else’s daughter" there were these warm regards:

- "Sending *your beautiful daughter’s **way*** a day so special and magical that she never forgets it. May her heart always be a container for happiness".

I can't twig the meaning of the first sentence to the fullest, specifically the consistence of the line "way-day".
And which of the objects (direct or indirect) is "way" a part of?

Comment: The answer is correct - but just to point out that the sentence as written, whilst technically 'correct' & very 'greetings card' in style, is actually so ultimately poor in content as to make any card manufacturer wonder why they still employ that particular copy-writer ;))

Answer (score 3):

"A day so special..." is the direct object of "sending". With a simplified sentence it could go directly after the verb:

- Sending [a special day] [your daughter's way].

"Your daughter's way" is the direction of the sending. "Send it my way" is an colloquial way of saying "send it to me".

Comment: Thank you very much. Is "to send someone a day" an idiom or can it be interpreted directly? I.e. in what of its meanings is "a day" being used here?

Comment: Not an idiom, just a figurative way of saying you hope someone has a great day.

Comment: There will be one more interesting quirk in my vocabulary. You've broken down all the nuances for me. (I hope I put up the right idiom?) :))

Comment: "Sending _a wish for_ a day..."would be a more usual way to put it. Also, though we do use "send wishes someone's way", it makes the sentence unduly complicated. "Wishing your daughter a day..." would have been simpler.

Comment: @KateBunting I think your suggested wording slightly dilutes the message: sending someone a wish for something is like saying you hope they have something; the original wording is more confident, like saying "I'm sure you'll have a wonderful day". I agree the sentence is a bit over-complicated, though; I rather expected there to be a rhyme or rhythm to explain why it was arranged that way.

Comment: @IMSoP - The OP asked what the sentence meant. You can't literally 'send a day', so the meaning is obviously "I wish her a special day".